# Constructing real numbers using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, textbook-recommendation

$\mathbb{R}$ is generally constructed as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. As Cauchy Completeness and Archimedean Property together are equivalent to the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there should be a method to construct $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ using the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

So, is there such a method? If so, could someone point me towards some resources related to this?

Comment: A corresponding [math.se] post: [Constructing Real Numbers using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664141)

Comment: That's my post. I didn't get a response there, so I've asked here.

Comment: Yes, it is [recommended to link the posts to each other](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) when [meta-tag:cross-posting]. That's why I commented under both psots.

Comment: I think the difficulty is that, whereas a Cauchy sequence or a Dedekind cut determines a single real, a bounded sequence determines, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, a nonempty *set* of reals, namely the set of accumulation points. So to produce a definition of the reals, you'd need to pick out one real from that set. It can certainly be done; e.g., the set has a largest element. But it looks ugly to me.

Comment: "Didn't get an answer" in 13 hours?  I recommend allowing 3 days before concluding you won't get an answer.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak. I did not know of this policy.